# All roots of a polynomial are inside the unit circle

Tags: integration

How to compute the following integral?

$\int_0^1 P_j(x)dx$, where $P_j(x) = \prod\limits_{i=0,i\ne j}^n(x+i)$?

I met this problem when doing estimation on the roots of the following polynomial.

All roots of polynomial $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M-1}\beta_i r^{M-1-i}$ are inside unit circle, i.e. $\vert r_i\vert<1$.

where $\beta_i = \frac{(-1)^{i}}{i!(M-1-i)!}\int_0^1 \prod\limits_{j=0,j\ne i}^{M-1}(x+j)dx$

Comment: what integrals can you compute?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: If you generalize the factors to $(x+a_i )$ (you can always set $a_i =i$ later), you can get a recursion by using $\partial /\partial a_i $ operations.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $P(x):=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)$ is a rising factorial, and therefore

\begin{equation*}
 P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \brack k} x^k.
\end{equation*}

The coefficients are [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Thus,

\begin{equation*}
 \int_0^1 P_j(x) dx = \int_0^1 P(x)\frac{dx}{x+j} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \brack k} \int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{x+j}\ dx
\end{equation*}

A closed form for the inner integral is available after a change of variable $y=x+j$.